# A Schauder basic sequence in $\ell^1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, schauder-basis

Denote by $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ the canonical basis of $\ell_1$, and let $(w_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of positive real numbers.  Define the vectors $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ by setting $x_1=e_1$ and
$$
x_n=w_ne_n-w_{n-1}e_{n-1},\;\;\;n\geqslant 2.
$$
Is it true that $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Schauder basic sequence?

This is true in case $w_n\equiv c$ for some constant $c>0$.  But, I would like to know whether it is true for an arbitrary sequence $(w_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of positive scalars.

Thanks!

Comment: If $(w_n)^∞_{n=1}$ is not bounded then we might have a problem. For example, consider the transformation from the standard basis to the new, this is not a bounded operator, and that might be a problem. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Physor Thank you, but bases don't need to be bounded like that in general.

Comment: Isn't $x_1+x_2+\cdots x_n=w_ne_n$? So if the $w_n$ have limit 0, $(x_n)$ is not basic.